# Implementing RadioCheckbox in Lightning not working with Locker service enabled

Tags: lightning-aura-components, locker-service

My aim is to have a radio checkbox field, my current below implementation worked properly when locker service was disabled. But when locker service is enabled this is not working. Please help me.

```
<aura:component >
    <ltng:require styles="/resource/slds0122/assets/styles/salesforce-lightning-design-system.min.css" />

    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" />

    <aura:attribute name="exampleList" type="String[]"/>
    <aura:attribute name="previousIndex" type="Integer" default="-1"/>

    <table class="slds-table slds-table--bordered slds-table--cell-buffer">
        <tbody>
            <aura:iteration items="{!v.exampleList}" var="item">
                <tr class="slds-hint-parent">
                    <td>
                        <ui:inputRadio change="{!c.radioSelect}" class="radio" />
                    </td>
                    <th>
                        {!item}
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </aura:iteration>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</aura:component>
```

Controller:

```
({
    doInit : function(component) {
        var items = [];
        for(var i=0;i<7;i++){
            var item = "Item_"+i;
            items.push(item);
        }
        component.set("v.exampleList",items);
    },

    radioSelect : function(component) {
        var index = component.get("v.previousIndex");
        var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("radio");
        if (index != "-1") {
            elements[index].checked = false;
        }
        for ( var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
            if (elements[i].checked)
                index = i;
        }
        component.set("v.previousIndex", index);
    }
})
```

When locker service is enabled, document.getElementsByClassName is returning null and the elements length is 0. How to implement this with Locker service enabled. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution, below is the code.

```
<aura:component >
    <ltng:require styles="/resource/slds0122/assets/styles/salesforce-lightning-design-system.min.css" />

    <aura:attribute name="exampleList" type="String[]" default="item_0,item_1,item_2,item_3,item_4"/>

    <table class="slds-table slds-table--bordered slds-table--cell-buffer">
        <tbody>
            <aura:iteration items="{!v.exampleList}" var="item" indexVar="index">
                <tr class="slds-hint-parent">
                    <td>
                        <ui:inputRadio name="radioElements" text="{!index}" label="{!item}" change="{!c.radioSelect}"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </aura:iteration>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</aura:component>
```

Controller:

```
({
    radioSelect : function(cmp, evt) {
        var elem = evt.getSource();
        console.log(elem.get("v.text"));  //To get the index of List
        console.log(elem.get("v.label")); //TO get the label of List
    },
})
```

I have used aura:iteration attribute indexVar in text attribute of inputRadio to get the index of the selected Item.
Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I will try to reproduce the issue, but there is a different and probably better way to solve your problem.

First, something like `document.getElementsByClassName("radio")` can become an issue on a multitenancy platform like Lightning. Your component can be on a page where other developers are also using the `"radio"` class name to tag their elements in order to apply CSS or retrieve them with JavaScript.

Even if you are developing a standalone application, you might want to develop components or at the very least development practices that are suited for such a scenario.

And even if you had a unique name, you probably want to be sure that two instances of the same component will not interfere with each other.

The solution I am proposing does respect encapsulation, and will only return components that exist within your lexical scope (between you opening and closing `<aura:component>` or `<aura:application>` tag).

Instead of using this pair:

```
<ui:inputRadio change="{!c.radioSelect}" class="radio" />

var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("radio");
```

You can use `aura:id`:

```
<ui:inputRadio change="{!c.radioSelect}" aura:id="radio" />

var radioComponents = component.find("radio");
```

You then interact with the  component instead of going to the underlying DOM API by using:

```
componentList[index].set("v.checked", false);
```

And

```
if (componentList[i].get("v.checked"))
            index = i;
```

Or something along those lines!

Comment: Thank you for your support @Paradis, the information you mentioned about document.getElementsByClassName will be an useful input to me. I have found a more easy solution, please look into my comment. Thank you again.

Comment: Perfect. It's a cleaner to stay away from the DOM most cases.